# pgfplots: ybars not at the numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a list `9, 11, 7, 1, 6, 4, 3, 8, 10, 5, 2` ant want to plot `ybar`s from these values at the positions *1*, 2, 3,...,11.

Why are my bars somewhere and not at these positions, if I use

```
\foreach \col in {0,1,...,5}{
\addplot table[x expr=\col+1, y index=\col]{\mytable};
}
```

What do I have to do?

PS: I do not know whether the foreach-loop is here the right thing to do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{
9, 11, 7, 1, 6, 4, 3, 8, 10, 5, 2
}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar, 
nodes near coords,
ymin=0,
xtick={1,...,10},
]
\foreach \col in {0,1,...,5}{
\addplot table[x expr=\col+1, y index=\col]{\mytable};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}`, you'll see, that `\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}` is a separate plot. // `\foreach \col in {0,1,...,5}` overlays 6 different plot, changing colors. Do you intend that? // Looks like you either need coordnate pairs (1,9) (2,11) etc., or really a xy table.

Comment: Oh no no. The input should be this one-line-table (this is created otherwise). So dumb it may sound.

Answer (score 2):

`bar shift=0pt` is needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{
9, 11, 7, 1, 6, 4, 3, 8, 10, 5, 2
}{\mytable}
\section{Table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\mytable}
\section{A Part of the Table and x+1 shifted}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar, 
bar shift=0pt, 
nodes near coords,
]
\foreach \col in {0,1,...,5}{% a part of the table and x+1 shifted
\addplot table[x expr=\col+1, y index=\col]{\mytable};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```